# Logo center in responsive website?

Tags: wordpress

Hello using a child theme, getting all the other elements working with the responsive design - just not the logo?

[link to site](http://www.seasonalharvest.co.uk/)

Using this code at the moment;

```
header#masthead hgroup .logo img {
vertical-align: bottom;
height: 80px;
width: 300px;
margin-left: 390px;
}
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for your `CSS`

```
header#masthead hgroup .logo {
display: block;
float: left;
max-width: 100%;
position: relative;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -150px;
}
header#masthead hgroup .logo img {
vertical-align: bottom;
height: 80px;
width: 300px;
}
```

No need for big margin-left. the code on the .logo div moves the logo 50% across the screen, to center it completely, you then have to remove half the width with a margin-left: -150px.

I tried the code out on your website so it should work. Hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

These two lines

```
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
```

are a good place to start to center something.

Common reasons for that not to work is if the element is `float`ing or has its `position` set to something besides static. In those cases you can try `float: none;`, or `position: static;` or `position: relative;`. In the case of `relative` be sure to also set the relevant `top`, `bottom`, `left`, and `right` properties.

There are a many cases where none of these things will help, but in your case and in most simple cases, the above will get you there.